# Memory leak when 'registering' objects into a static array in the same class

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, static-methods

I want to create a fixed number of instances of a given class and each time I create one I want to add it to a `vector` which is a `static member` in the same class. I tried the following code but it doesn't seem to work (in the main function the `Column::GetColumns()` call returns an empty `vector`) plus it leaks memory (Valgrind complains about `kUsername` not being destroyed).
Any suggestion is highly appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;
using std::vector;

class Column {
 public:
  static const Column kUsername;
  static const Column kPassword;

  static vector<Column*> GetColumns() {
    return columns_;
  }

  string GetColumnName() const {
    return column_name_;
  }

 private:
  static vector<Column*> columns_;

  explicit Column(const string& column_name) : column_name_(column_name) {
    columns_.push_back(this);
  }

  Column(const Column& column) : column_name_(column.column_name_) {}

  virtual ~Column() {}

  string column_name_;
};

const Column Column::kUsername("Username");
const Column Column::kPassword("Password");

vector<Column*> Column::columns_;

int main(void) {
  cout << Column::kUsername.GetColumnName() << endl;
  cout << Column::kPassword.GetColumnName() << endl;

  const vector<Column*>& columns = Column::GetColumns();
  for (vector<Column*>::const_iterator it = columns.begin();
       it != columns.end();
       ++it) {
    cout << (*it)->GetColumnName() << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What "doesn't work" about it? What leaks memory?

Comment: The Column::GetColumns() call in main returns an empty array and Valgrind says that the kUsername object is not destroyed.

Comment: Username and Password should be printed twice, once by the cout statements at the start of the main function and once in the for loop. From your output on the page you sent it looks like they are only printed once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're relying on a particular order of initialization for your static objects.  On these two lines:

```
const Column Column::kUsername("Username");
const Column Column::kPassword("Password");
```

You are calling this constructor:

```
explicit Column(const string& column_name) : column_name_(column_name) {
    columns_.push_back(this);
}
```

This assumes that the object columns_ has been initialized already.  Apparently, it has not.  Read this: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.14 from 10.14 through 10.18

Answer (score 2):

The reason that you're not getting the words "Username" and "Password" printed twice is because of a problem with the ordering and initialization of your static objects.  What's occuring right now is that your two objects `Column::kUsername` and then `Column Column::kPassword` are being initialized before `main()` is run, and when their constructors are called, they are adding the address of their objects to the `Column::columns_` vector object.  But the constructor for `Column::columns_` hasn't been called yet due to the compiler's selected initialization order of the static objects in the code module ... So when the compiler does actually call the constructor for `Column::columns_`, it re-initializes the values of the vector, and you therefore loose the memory that was already allocated to save the values of the two pointers you pushed back during the constructors of `Column::kUsername` and `Column Column::kPassword` ... this is why Valgrind is complaining about leaked memory ... the vector wasn't properly destructed before it was re-initialized by the call to the vector's default constructor during the static object initialization stage performed by the compiler.